# Is it correct to answer the question “who is there?” by “I”?

Tags: sentence-usage, colloquial-language, personal-pronouns

Somebody on quora stated that “I.” is a possible answer to the question “Who is there?”, making “I.” the shortest English sentence whatsoever.

I'm not a native speaker but wouldn't the natural answer to “Who is there?” be “It's me.”?

Is “I.” acceptable for colloquial use by native speakers?

Comment: "It is I" is the formally correct answer (which could in theory be shortened to "I"), but, as you say, the normal colloquial answer would be "It's me".

Comment: Can you imagine a question whose answer could be simply "I"?

Comment: I did say 'in theory'! Any question to which the answer is to identify oneself - though in practice the answer would be "I do", "I am" etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is NO single correct way to answer the question.
Depending on the context, you can choose freely from:

**It's me** (as you suggest, if you recognise the voice)

**I am** (if you prefer, but not **It's I:** sounds theatrical).

**It's John/Jenny etc** (if you need to identify yourself to friend)

**It's John/Jenny Smith** (if you need to identify yourself more formally)

**It's your friend/brother/sister/mate/colleague..and so on**

Comment: 'sounds theatrical' - I can imagine Peter Cushing saying it in a Hammer film, but I think he would say 'It is I".

Comment: Richmal Crompton's William (crestfallen): Father, it was me that broke Mr Smith's window, with my catapult. Father: It was _I_, William. Willam (brightening) I say, Father, it's jolly decent of you to take the blame for me!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I suspect the king might say **It is I** when knocking on the door (if kings knock on doors) unless the proper form is **It is we**..

Comment: "It is I" said the sparrow, "with my little bow and arrow. I killed cock robin."

Comment: A Bishop or a university rector, also, I gather.